# Распарсить объект объектов и преобразовать его в объект с массивами js

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, arraylist, obj

У меня есть объект объектов:

```
    let object2 = {
{name: 'a', group: 'a'},
{name: 'b', group 'a'},
{name: 'c', group: 'b'}
}
```

Мне нужно преобразовать его в структуру, которая будет подходить для поиска по выпадающему меню чтобы при поиске отображалась найденная группа и совпадающие продукты.
Помогите мне понять в каком виде лучше сохранить данные объекты и какова будет реализация.
У меня на данный момент есть такой вариант сохранения:
сохранить как отдельные объекты, объединенные по группе

```
let obj1 = {group: 'a',
product: [
'a', 'b']},
{group: 'b',
product: ['c']}
```

Как реализовать такое сохранение?

Comment: В выпадающем меню Вы что выбираете? name или group? Опишите более подробно..

Comment: Может быть у Вас массив объектов? Так как приведённый Вами код негоден.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы выполняете поиск по группе, то преобразовать лучше в объект, где ключом будет выступать имя группы, а значением являться массив продуктов:

```js
var arr = [
  {name: 'lorem', group: 'a'},
  {name: 'ipsum', group: 'a'},
  {name: 'dolor', group: 'b'},
  {name: 'sit', group: 'b'},
  {name: 'a met', group: 'b'}
], obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(item){
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(item.group) === false){
    obj[item.group] = [];
  }
  obj[item.group].push(item.name);
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен с **XelaNimed** по поводу новой структуры.
Предложу еще такой вариант...

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'lorem', group: 'a'},
  {name: 'ipsum', group: 'a'},
  {name: 'dolor', group: 'b'},
  {name: 'sit', group: 'b'},
  {name: 'a met', group: 'b'}
]
const obj = arr.reduce((o, e) => (o[e.group] = o[e.group] ? [...o[e.group], e.name] : [e.name], o), {})
console.log(obj)
```